# How to use different type of schema in an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have this schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    documento: []
});
```

and this types of documents:

```
var RgSchema = new Schema({
    tipo: 'RG',
    numero: stringType(),
    orgaoEmissor: stringType(),
    dataExpedicao: dateType()
});

var CpfSchema = new Schema({
    tipo: 'CPF',
    numero: stringType()
});
```

how to set different types of schema (RgSchema or CpfSchema) in the `documento: []`?

A kind of this:

```
documento: [RgSchema || CpfSchema]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can achieve this in current version of mongoose. The option I would suggest you to have a common schema for the both with `tipo` as `enum`.

```
var CommonSchema = new Schema({
    tipo: {type:String, enum: ['RG', 'CPF']}
    numero: stringType(),
    orgaoEmissor: stringType(),
    dataExpedicao: dateType()
});
```

Other option is to use different `ref` for different Schema.

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
        documenRG: [],
        documenCPF: []

    });
```

Comment: I will use the second option, because the in my situation, CPF dont have this properties `orgaoEmissor: stringType(), dataExpedicao: dateType()`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can one use the second option if the order of the array elements (with mixed types) is important?

Comment: @Tom The User schema contains a "documento" array which may look like this: `[{RGref:{...}, CPFref:null}, {RGref:null, CPFref:{...}}, {RGref:{...}, CPFref:null}]`. The "UserSchema" or "CommonSchema" in @Jayram's answer facilitates this.

Comment: Can we not simply do this documento: [RgSchema || CpfSchema] in latest mongoose version ^5.3.20 ....this would be the easiest and most self explanatory

Comment: I have the exact same question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788956/mongoose-schema-declare-with-array-of-different-nested-schemas ...can anyone help me please?