# mongoose schema declare with array of different nested schemas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to know whether my below schema definition for PersonSchema will work or not. Is it possible to declare a schema type like my example?

I mean, I want my PersonSchema to be an Array of type EmployedPersonSchema(object) or of type UnEmployedPersonSchema(object). Can I use the OR operator like below?

```
const EmployedPersonSchema = new Schema({
 employeeID: String,
 taxNumber: Number
});
const UnEmployedPersonSchema = new Schema({
 personID: String;
 age: Number,
 pensionNumber: Number
});
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
 persons:{
    type: [EmployedPersonSchema || UnEmployedPersonSchema],
    default: []
 }
});
```

Is it the best way to do it or there are other better ways? Any help?

**DATA should look like below in my MongoDB:**

```
"persons" : [
            {
             employeeID: "001",
             taxNumber: 39765
            },
            {
             personID: "901"
             age: 68,
             pensionNumber: 2345
            }
           ]
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html -> what does arrays of subdocuments mean in their documentation ? children: [childSchema || grandChildSchema] possible to do this now???